# Excluding Library/Application Support from backup to iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, backup, icloud

My app got rejected because it Backups too much data to iCloud.
WHen I exclude Libraries folder, it stores 0Mb to iCloud, so I figure out, something in Libraries I should exclude.

Now, I read that excluding whole Library folder from backup is not a good practise as well, so I was aiming to exclude only Libraries/Application Support.

Here is my code for doing that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,     
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *supportFiles = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
(@"/Application Support")];
NSURL *pathURL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:supportFiles];
[Controller addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:pathURL];
return YES;
}

+ (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
if(!success){
    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
}
NSLog(@"Prevent backup method called without error. %@ excluded from backup.",[URL 
lastPathComponent]);
return success;
}
```

Error excluding Application Support from backup Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x1462dab0 {NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Applications/0BF562C9-534A-480F-AE7F-88B19DFBD612/Library/Application%20Support, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/0BF562C9-534A-480F-AE7F-88B19DFBD612/Library/Application Support, NSUnderlyingError=0x1462da40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. **No such file or directory**

Does anyone sees what am I doing wrong?
Also, is there any way to see all the documents that are in Libraries, so I can chose which ones not to backup?